# Measure theory and probability (Adams and Guillemin) chapter 1.3 Theorem 18 proof

Tags: measure-theory

While reading Measure Theory and Probability by Adams and Guillemin (2nd ed.), I encountered Theorem 18 (Chapter 1.3, page 33) which makes three claims the second of which is

2. For $A \in \mathcal{M}_F, \mu^*(A)<\infty.$

where

$\mu^*$ is an outer measure over $2^X$ and $\mathcal{M}_F$ was introduced just before as the closure of a ring of sets $\mathcal{R}$ in $2^X$ i.e. $A \in \mathcal{M}_F$ if and only if there exists a sequence of sets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{R}$ such that $d(A_i, A)\rightarrow 0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ with distance $d$ the outer measure of the symmetric difference, so $d(A,B) = \mu^*((A-B) \cup (B-A))$.

The proof of 2. then argues: $A \in \mathcal{M}_F$ implies that there is a sequence $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{R}$ with $A_i \rightarrow A$. For some $n$, then, $d(A_n, A) < 1.$ Thus $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(A_n) + 1 < \infty.$

I don't understand how "$<\infty$" follows here. This seems to be using a result from just before (Proposition 16) which showed that if $A, B \in 2^X$ with either $\mu^*(A)$ or $\mu^*(B)$ finite we get $|\mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B)| \leq d(A,B)$. Now if $\mu^*(A_n)$ were finite I would understand the above implication, but that was never given, nor can I see how that unstated assumption follows from anywhere else in the text.

Comment: Isn't $\mu$ assumed to finite on sets in $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: $\mu$ is defined to be nonnegative "that is, to each $A \in \mathcal{R}$, $\mu$ assigns a nonnegative number $\mu(A)$".
So does nonnegative mean it can't assume $+\infty$?

Comment: Ah now I got it after some confusion of concepts. So the outer measure $\mu^*$ behaves like $\mu$ on the ring of sets $\mathcal{R}$ and of course $\mu$ has to assign some finite number to every set you plug in.

Comment: Yes,  the phrase "that is, to each $A\in\mathcal{R}$, $\mu$ assigns a nonnegative number $\mu(A)$", means that $\mu(A)$ is finite and non-negative. Of course there are measures that may have infinite values, but it is not the case here.